# How build membership site with EE?

Tags: members

There are many add-ons available on the market, but their taget is too high for my needs. I have about three hundred members present, and voorei offer payment services through membership.

I was wondering if there is a solution that is less costly and difficult to implement extensions as carthrob.

I was considering the form paypal, and I cheidevo if you can implement this with a mebership.

Comment: Can you please revise your question to make it less broad? There are many factors involved in building membership sites. Please let us know what your requirements are, what you're considering doing, what problems you're having, etc, so that it can be answered.

Comment: Sorry for my english,.I want to sell membership via pay pal (in Italy there no support for Stripe). There are many plugin, addon for ee (cartthrob), but they are out od scope for my project. I need a simple system, but seem there is no one, so I ask if there i some.

Comment: Can you please edit your original question, and add some more information about what you are trying to achieve, and for example why cartthrob is out of scope for your project?

Answer (score 1):

For selling membership through PayPal I think this would be your best option: http://www.membrr.com/

I use it on my site to sell paid premium membership and it works great.